# Sequelize - validate based on associations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, validation, sequelize.js

I'm using PostgreSQL and Sequelize for my project.

I have 2 models, 1 is `Event` which, among other fields, has `questions` field, which is an array of strings, and also I have another model, `Application`, which belongs to `Event` model and has, among other fields, the field `answers`, which is the array of strings as well.

What I need to implement is a custom validator which will make `Application` model invalid if the `questions` amount on `Application` is not the same as the amount of `answers` in `Event` it belongs to. It should work both when creating and updating an `Application` model.

For now I've implemented it as a check in the endpoint handler, but this does not seem to me as a good solution, as I want to move each piece of the model's logic to the model itself instead of handling it in the controller.

So, my question is: is there a way to implement it the way I want it?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8770) . It might help you.